# Numerically solve an integral equation

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, integral-equations

Let $F(s)$ be a cdf on $[0,\infty[$, we have the following integral equation for $k \geq 2$ a natural number and $\lambda \in ]0,1[$. I would like to (numerically) solve the following equation:
$$
F(s) = F(0) + \lambda \int_0^s F(u) du + \lambda \int_0^s(1-(1-F(u))^k) e^{u-s} du
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
G(s)=\int_0^s(1−(1−F(u))^k)e^{u-s}du
$$
then
$$
e^s(G'(s)+G(s))=(e^sG(s))'=(1−(1−F(s))^k)e^s\\
G'(s)=1-G(s)−(1−F(s))^k
$$
Replacing the integral with $G$ and taking the derivative of the original equation gives
$$
F'(s)=λF(s)+λG'(s)
$$
Thus you get a coupled system of two differential equations that you can solve with the ODE solver of your choice.

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you very much!