# ODE solver giving unexpected result

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, numerical-methods

I have the following coupled ODEs:
$$
\begin{cases}
F'(s) & = \lambda F(s) - \lambda (1 - (1 - F(s))^2) + \lambda H'(s)\\
H'(s) & = 1 - H(s) - (1 - F(s))^2,
\end{cases}
$$
with boundary condition $F(0) = 1-\lambda, H(0) = 0$, here $\lambda \in ]0,1[$. The solution for $F$ I am looking for is a Cummulative Distribution Function (CDF), but when I solve these coupled ODEs with these boundary conditions, I get a result which is not a CDF at all. The question is: how to find the correct solution OR did I make a mistake in deriving these ODEs and do these ODEs indeed not give a CDF as a possible solution?

I am using the Python solve [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)

Comment: It seems like $H(s) = 0$ solves the second equation. Don't know whether you expect this to happen. In particular for $\lambda$ near to 1 you would have decreasing $F$ (at least near to zero). Which is not the behaviour of a CDF.

Comment: I made a typo! see my correction

Comment: I would indeed not expect $H(s) = 0$ as I have defined (in my application):

$H(s) = \int_0^s (1-(1-F(u))^k) e^{u-s} du$

Comment: Note that this ODE system is in various places different from my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2540088/115115. However, even in the original integral equation there is no reason that $F$ should stabilize at $1$. Set $F(0)$ close to $1$ then both integrands are close to $1$ and thus continue to contribute essentially to the values of $F(t)$. Please revisit the original ideas in the construction of the integral equation.

Comment: It is indeed different than in the original post, but I made a mistake in writing the integral equation it was $(1-e^{u-s})$ instead of $e^{u-s}$ which had to be used thus the integral equation was:
$
F(s) = F(0) + \lambda \int_0^s F(u) du + \lambda \int_0^s(1-(1-F(u))^k) (1-e^{u-s}) du
$
which then, by applying the ideas suggested by yourself yield the ODEs given in this question.

Comment: I also tried to do an iteration on the integral equation:
$
F_k(s) = F_{k-1}(0) + \lambda \int_0^s F_{k-1}(u) du + \lambda \int_0^s(1-(1-F(u))^k)(1-e^{u-s})du.
$
But this also does not yield a CDF even after one step when $F_0$ is a CDF, $F_1$ isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the integral equation as given in the comments
$$
F(s) = F(0) + \lambda \int_0^s F(u) du + \lambda \int_0^s(1-(1-F(u))^k) (1-e^{u-s}) du
$$
set again $H(s)= \int_0^s(1-(1-F(u))^k)e^{u-s}du$. Then
$$
H'(s)+H(s)=(1-(1-F(s))^k)
$$
Now taking the derivative of the first equation gives
$$
F'(s)=λ(F(s)+(1-(1-F(u))^k)-H'(s))=λ(F(s)+H(s)).
$$
The stationary points of this system satisfy $0=f+h$, $h=1-(1-f)^k$ which for $k=2$ results in  the quadratic equation $$0=1+f-(1-f)^2=3f-f^2$$ which has a stationary point at $f=0$ and $f=3$. Numerical integration confirms that result.

Now if the sign of the first integral were changed, 
$$
F(s) = F(0) - \lambda \int_0^s F(u) du + \lambda \int_0^s(1-(1-F(u))^k) (1-e^{u-s}) du
$$
then the system 
\begin{align}
F(s)&=λ(-F(s)+H(s))\\
H'(s)&=1-H(s)-(1-F(s))^k
\end{align}
has its stationary points at $f=h=1-(1-f)^k$, that is, at $f=h=0$ and $f=h=1$, as required for a CDF that goes from asymptotically zero to asymptotically one. One would have to explore the stability and basins of attraction for these stationary points, monotonicity is not a given as in the case of scalar first order ODE.

A numerical example integration gives

```
def deriv(y,a): F,H = y; return [a*(-F+H), 1-H-(1-F)**2]
y0 = [0.3, 0]
a = 0.2
tp = np.linspace(0,30,151)
tm = np.linspace(0,-5,21)
solp=odeint(lambda y,t: deriv(y,0.2), [ 0.1, 0], tp)
solm=odeint(lambda y,t: deriv(y,0.2), [ 0.1, 0], tm)
plt.plot(tp,solp[:,0],tm,solm[:,0]); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

with the result

[image]

However, at $s=0$ with $H(0)=0$ one has $F'(0)=-λF(0)$ so that the solution has an initial negative slope which is untypical for CDF.

Comment: Thank you, the CDF is supposed to start in $0$ and is only defined on $]0,\infty[$ thus I believe that your remark of changing the sign is indeed justified as  then your plot on $]0,\infty[$ looks exactly as expected! Thank you very much I will redo my computations check if you are indeed correct (which I assume you will be).

Comment: I do observe a small decrease of $F$ on $]0,\varepsilon[$ for small $\varepsilon$, but I will try to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the equation in the following simple formulation (by simply inserting the definition of $H'$):
\begin{align}
F' & = \lambda (F - H) \\
H' & = 1 - H - (1 - F)^2
\end{align}

This equation hast two fixed points:
\begin{align}
H &= 0 , \ F = 0 \\
H &= 1, \ F = 1
\end{align}

So you can imagine that if you start somewhere between $0$ and $1$ you might converge to one of these fixed points. But is one attractive and one repulsive?

To answer this question we actually look at another property. Since $F$ is a CDF it's supposed to be monotonically increasing (and converging to $1$). So we need $$D =  H - F < 0$$
So we write the differential equation for $D$ and $F$:
\begin{align}
F' &= -\lambda D \\
D' &= (\lambda - 1)D + F(1-F)
\end{align}
We see that there is no particular reason for the latter equation to stay negative. In any case we can solve the equation numerically. First we see that the negativity of $D$ is not satisfied. Furthermore on large scales we converge to $0$ and not to $1$.
[image]

Comment: Note that w.r.t. the previous answer I solved a different ODE (the one from the question).

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer giving insights in the problem, but as the answer of LultzL is even better and I can only accept one as "the answer" I have to accept his one.
I do still really appreciate your answer and it helps me a lot in understanding how to analyze ODEs!